# Need help on finding appropriate Laravel seeder for German cities and states

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I need help on finding right package, or database seeder for German cities, that have appropriate states linked to them and also with postal code values. Does someone know any, or is there some other way to implement that in my Laravel application? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this json data can help you https://github.com/pensnarik/german-cities
But that json does not has Postal Code value. If you have time maybe you can extract postal code from this url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zauberware/postal-codes-json-xml-csv/master/data/DE/zipcodes.de.json

Comment: How would I set this in my laravel seeder https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zauberware/postal-codes-json-xml-csv/master/data/DE/zipcodes.de.json . can you help by example?

Comment: you can write artisan command. In artisan command you created you can create script to get json content and input them to your table